# Trouble using EOSIO built in crypto library (can't resolve headers)

Tags: smart-contract, c++, cryptography

I ran eosio-init on the newest CDT (1.7) and made a -bare project.

newtest.cpp

```
#include "newtest.hpp"
ACTION newtest::hi( name nm ) {
   /* fill in action body */
   print_f("Name : %\n",nm);
}
```

newtest.hpp

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/core/eosio/crypto.hpp>
using namespace eosio;

CONTRACT newtest : public contract {
   public:
      using contract::contract;

      ACTION hi( name nm );

      using hi_action = action_wrapper<"hi"_n, &newtest::hi>;
};
```

When I run `eosio-cpp -abigen newtest.cpp`:

```
/tmp/newtest.cpp:8:10: fatal error: 'eosiolib/datastream.hpp' file not found
#include <eosiolib/datastream.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I tried also including `#include <eosiolib/crypto.h>`, but this isn't found.

How do I go about doing crypto functions like `sha256` in EOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct library is now
`#include <eosio/crypto.hpp>`